# AngularJS - Create Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

Using one drag and drop plugin for passing data, `ondrop` event fetching data like below

**Ctrl**

```
var streamArr = [];
$scope.onDrop = function (data, dragElement, dropElement, event) {
    streamArr.push({'userId':userId,'divid':divId,'userName':userName,'streamingState':$rootScope.route});
});
```

**Output**

```
10
divPictureBox00
User1
live
```

Now, whenever user drop something I need to push the data in one array so the resulting itesm would be like below

```
streamArr: [
{userId: 10, divId: 'divPictureBox00', userName: 'User1', streamingState:'live'},
{userId: 11, divId: 'divPictureBox01', userName: 'User2', streamingState:'live'},
{userId: 12, divId: 'divPictureBox02', userName: 'User3', streamingState:'recorded'},
{userId: 10, divId: 'divPictureBox00', userName: 'User1', streamingState:'live'},
]
```

But the data is not being pushed in that array. How do I go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are dealing with the same object throughout. Try creating a new object every time you call the function and then push the object in the array.

```
var streamArr = [];
$scope.onDrop = function (data, dragElement, dropElement, event) {
var obj = new Object();
obj.userId = userId;
obj.divId = divId;
obj.userName = userName;
obj.streamingState = $rootScope.route;

streamArr.push(obj);
```

});

Comment: The creates multiple objects like `[Object { userId=1480,  divId="divPictureBox00",  userName="User1"},
Object { userId=1480,  divId="divPictureBox00",  userName="User1"},
Object { userId=1480,  divId="divPictureBox01",  userName="User2"}]`. How do I make into single object ?